# How to disable default 404/401/400.. error messages in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to use htaccess to show 404/401/400 ... error messages but my website always shows errors which CI default error messages. I dont want to use CI error function or custom it. Is the anyway to disable that ?

I tried this in my htaccess file but not working.

```
RewriteEngine on 

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a rewriteRule for your error pages.

RewriteRule is faster then the ErrorDocument directive.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite all non existent dirs and files to /404.html

Comment: sir,  how about 401,400 ,403 ,500 ? RewriteRule  could work with them ?